# How to trigger window resize event using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, testing

I'm trying to trigger resize event using plain js for testing purpose, but `window.resizeTo()` and `window.resizeBy()` don't trigger the event according to the modern browsers prevent these actions. I tried jquery `$(window).trigger('resize');` but it works only for events that attached via jquery like `$(window).on('resize', handler);`. however in my case the project I am working on uses plain javascript.

example

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    console.log('window has been resized !');
});

// or even using global onresize
window.onresize = function() {
    console.log('window has been resized!');
};
```

Comment: If your event listener is a named function you can just call that function directly (assuming it doesn't need to use the `event` object).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are most likely getting downvoted as people will see it [as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1), however from the [you might not need jquery website](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#trigger_custom):

IE9+

Trigger native

```
// For a full list of event types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent
var el = document; // This can be your element on which to trigger the event
var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
event.initEvent('resize', true, false);
el.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Trigger custom

```
var el = document; // This can be your element on which to trigger the event
if (window.CustomEvent) {
  var event = new CustomEvent('my-event', {detail: {some: 'data'}});
} else {
  var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
  event.initCustomEvent('my-event', true, true, {some: 'data'});
}

el.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: For people looking to trigger a resize event, use `resize`, not `change` in the call to `initEvent`.

Comment: Where did the "el" come from?

Comment: wherever the event was attached to. it could be `window` or a dom element.